# Configure Delete key to delete forward chars in Xterm

Tags: xterm

When using Xterm alone, I can use Delete and Backspace/ ^H as usual. But I'm using Xterm, invoked by a different program for its terminal, then Delete doesn't work. Delete just outputs **~**. Neither does Alt+Right/Left for skip forward/backward one word, instead outputting **;5D** & **;5C** respectively.

Is there any solutions for this? I'm thinking of binding Delete to RightArrow+Backspace, but I don't know how.

Comment: What is the value of the `$TERM` environment variable, when you're using Xterm alone, vs. when invoked by another program? The outputs you are seeing seem to be the visible parts of the expected character sequences produced by Xterm; it would be the job of the shell (or whatever is running within the Xterm window) to interpret them, usually with the help of the terminfo library.

Comment: $TERM= xterm in both cases. With standalone xterm, $term=xterm but when invoked by my work program, $term is undefinded.